# change border/color onFocus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to make script which changes color of border-bottom of div after having focus on

```
<input type="text">
```

and then changing back to default color after clicking somewhere else.

This is what i tried:

Css:

```
.div1 {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
```

Javacript:

```
function inputFocus(){ $(".div1").css("border-bottom","1px solid #ffba00"); };
```

Html:

```
<input type="text" onFocus="inputFocus();">
```

The first part (changing color on focus) works fine, however after clicking somewhere else (not having focus on input) it doesnt change back to normal style as set in css file.

any idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).css('border-bottom','1px solid #000');
    }).blur(
        function(){
            $(this).css('border-bottom','1px solid #ccc');
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2xXr6/1/).

Though if you're amenable to CSS:

```
input:focus,
input:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2xXr6/).

Comment: Your JavaScript functions exactly the same as the OP's original solution.  The CSS does not get rolled back when the field is blurred.

Comment: If you one of our answers solved your problem you should mark it as such so that user is rewarded.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).css('border-bottom-color','#ffba00');
});
$('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).css('border-bottom-color','#ccc');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using JavaScript to do this.  CSS has a `:focus` selector that is much more appropriate for this.

```
.div1 {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
.div1:focus {border-bottom:1px solid #ffba00;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shold add a function to onBlur event to rollback your change

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `onBlur` event.

JavaScript:

```
function inputBlur() {
    $(".div1").css("border-bottom","1px solid #ccc");
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="div1" onFocus="inputFocus();" onBlur="inputBlur();">
```

**However**, the better option will be using class toggling.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="myinput">
```

CSS:

```
.myinput {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

.myinput.active {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffba00;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".myinput").on("focus", function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }).on("blur", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling a function in html you can try this:

```
.border {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}

$("input[type='text']").focus(function(){
    $(this).addClass("border")
})

$("input[type='text']").blur(function(){
   $(this).removeClass("border");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because the changed css is not reverted after losing focus from control.

This would help:

```
<input type="text" onFocus="inputFocus();" onblur="inputBlur();">

function inputFocus(){ $(".div1").removeAttr('style'); };
```