# Change border of textbox red to when Validation Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, validation

I am making a web page in asp.net c# and I want to change the border color of textbox when it fails the validation.

For example : [image: See the red bordered texbox in this image]

Please tell me how can I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This sulation is easy, but a little bit dirty:

Specify an onClientClick attribute on your button and this JavaScript-Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function YourButtonClickEvent() {
        var validation = Page_ClientValidate();
        if (!validation) {
            for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).css("border-color", "red");
                }
            }
        }            
        return val;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: but is it not possible to use script on .cs page ?

Comment: @user1831272 Validation on server-side script (.cs file) is not a good idea. Why go to server for a simple validation which can be handled at client-side script (.js file) ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment. Server-side validation is essential.

Comment: Yes it is essential, but for the style change it isn't!

Comment: @tuxtimo I know. I think I misunderstood what Mr_Green meant by saying "validation on server-side script is not a good idea." I'm guessing he means that it isn't a good idea in the case of setting the text box border. It's just not clear and potentially misleading, as OP will still need server-side validation.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev sorry If my english is poor.. I meant that why go to server side for a small validation which can be handled at client side itself.. I meant Optimum approach. If there are big validations to be handled then doing this at server side will be good but this is small.

Answer (score 0):

using **jQuery** -- use on [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) Event

```
if(!validation)
{
   $('textboxid').css('border','1px solid red');
}
else
{
   $('textboxid').css('border','1px solid black');  //set to normal color
}
```

using **Javascript**  -- use on Blur event

```
document.getElementById('textboxId').Style.Border = "1px solid red";
```

For more information go through this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374187/1577396)**

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I am not providing code to the OP here. Anyway, I provided a link to refer.

Comment: OP asked how to add a border on validation fail.  This just shows how to add a border.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev yup you are right.. but I dont know how the validation should be bcos OP has not mentioned anything about it. The least I can do is `if(!validation){/*the above code here*/}`